# Could not find class "class_path" referenced from method y

Tags: android

On Samsung devices and some devices I am getting following error

```
E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
                                                    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
                                                    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-15 18:24:30.214 13931-13931/com.luharsutharsevasamaj.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.luharsutharsevasamaj.android.fragments.BrideFragment$1', referenced from method com.luharsutharsevasamaj.android.fragments.BrideFragment.registerOnClick
12-15 18:24:30.284 13931-13931/com.luharsutharsevasamaj.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.luharsutharsevasamaj.android.fragments.BrideFragment$1
                                                                                      at com.luharsutharsevasamaj.android.fragments.BrideFragment.registerOnClick(BrideFragment.java:163)
                                                                                      at com.luharsutharsevasamaj.android.fragments.BrideFragment.onActivityCreated(BrideFragment.java:140)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1983)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1092)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried following sites but couldn't help anything

[Android Studio E/dalvikvm: Could not find class... referenced from method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816684/android-studio-e-dalvikvm-could-not-find-class-referenced-from-method)

[Could not find method XXX, referenced from method YYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349244/could-not-find-method-xxx-referenced-from-method-yyy)

my gradle file for app level is below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.luharsutharsevasamaj.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.rampo.updatechecker:library:2.1.8'

}
```

Implemented MultidexApplication by below code

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
```

Anybody can help, thanks in Advance